# align form inputs on the same column

Tags: css

What's the best way to get the mins below next to the hr?

-I tried using columns and rows, but it de-centered everything.
-I tried floats, but it makes everything misaligned
-I tried boxes, but similar problems to columns and rows.

Thank you so much! :)

[image]

```
<form class="section-top-buffer text-center" style="margin-top:60px" id="live_form" method="POST" action="/suggest/" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

  {% csrf_token %}
  <!-- change the form action to your script url -->

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p style="font-weight:bold">Start </p>
        <p style="font-weight:bold">Hr </p>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="number" name="drugsrating" min="1" max="24" value="{{form.drugsrating.value}}">
        </fieldset>

        <p style="font-weight:bold">Min </p>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="number" name="petrating" min="0" max="59" value="{{form.petrating.value}}">
        </fieldset>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p style="font-weight:bold">End </p>
        <p style="font-weight:bold">Hr </p>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="number" name="friendshiprating" min="1" max="24" value="{{form.friendshiprating.value}}">
        </fieldset>

        <p style="font-weight:bold">Min </p>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="number" name="sleeprating" min="0" max="59" value="{{form.sleeprating.value}}">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End all row -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this one:

```
<form class="section-top-buffer text-center" style="margin-top:60px" id="live_form" method="POST" action="/suggest/" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

  {% csrf_token %}
  <!-- change the form action to your script url -->

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p style="font-weight:bold">Start </p>
        <span style="font-weight:bold">Hr </span>
        <fieldset style="display:inline-block">
          <input type="number" name="drugsrating" min="1" max="24" value="{{form.drugsrating.value}}">
        </fieldset>

        <span style="font-weight:bold">Min </span>
        <fieldset style="display:inline-block">
          <input type="number" name="petrating" min="0" max="59" value="{{form.petrating.value}}">
        </fieldset>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p style="font-weight:bold">End </p>
        <span style="font-weight:bold">Hr </span>
        <fieldset style="display:inline-block">
          <input type="number" name="friendshiprating" min="1" max="24" value="{{form.friendshiprating.value}}">
        </fieldset>

        <span style="font-weight:bold">Min </span>
        <fieldset style="display:inline-block">
          <input type="number" name="sleeprating" min="0" max="59" value="{{form.sleeprating.value}}">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End all row -->
</form>
```

as @Pyromonk mentioned `p` is a block element so use `span` instead

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help!!

Comment: Welcome anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a block element and so is `fieldset`. `input` is an inline element. If linebreaks are the problem you are facing, you should look into using a set of inline elements in succession, for example a `label` and an `input`. Block elements force a linebreak after themselves and inline elements don't, to put it in simple terms. I see absolutely no reason for using `fieldset` and `p` in your scenario, unless you absolutely have to. If you do, you can try setting their display to `inline-block`.

Further reading: [MDN :: Visual formatting model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model)